# How to cryptographically verify the authenticity and integrity of Mozilla releases (Firefox, Thunderbird, etc)

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, authentication, gnupg, data-integrity

For a given software release published by Mozilla, how can I cryptographically verify the authenticity and integrity of the file that I downloaded before I execute it to install that program?

Today I wanted to download firefox and thunderbird for Windows, but the download page said nothing about how to verify the release after download.

- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-release

I expected to see a message telling me the fingerprint of their release signing key, a link to further documentation, and links to [a] a manifest file (eg `SHA256SUMS`) and [b] a detached signature of that manifest file (eg `SHA256SUMS.asc`, `SHA256SUMS.sig`, `SHA256SUMS.gpg`, etc)

How can I preform this verification with mozilla products, such as firefox and thunderbird?

Comment: It does indeed appear that Mozilla Firefox uses GPG to sign manifests, but I cannot find where they actually put those manifests and their signatures https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2019/06/13/updated-firefox-gpg-key/

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't documented anywhere that I can find. I created a bug report for mozilla to add this documentation and link to it on the download page https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1681541#c2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windows** releases are signed using Authenticode, so the signature is embedded into the executable and the OS automatically verifies it upon launch against a Microsoft-maintained list of X.509 certificate authorities. The individual files extracted into 'C:\Program Files' are likewise Authenticode-signed when possible.

You can view the signature details in the file's "Properties" window, or using `sigcheck` (from [Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck)), or using `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` (PowerShell cmdlet), or using `signtool verify` (part of Windows developer kit), or using `osslsigncode verify` (available in many Linux distributions).

**Linux** releases (source and pre-compiled) *are* signed using PGP, with a detached signature being available at the same URL + `.asc` suffix. They're at
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/:

- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/83.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-83.0.tar.bz2
- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/83.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-83.0.tar.bz2.asc

(Mozilla's "[Downloading the source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives)" article points to https://archive.mozilla.org, but that is basically the same server with the same contents.)

Of course, for PGP to be useful *at all*, you need to find some other way to verify the signing key instead of just grabbing it from the same directory. It seems Mozilla publishes their release keys [on their blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20190826110212/https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2019/06/13/updated-firefox-gpg-key/).

As long as you're dealing with single files, **a separate "SUMS" manifest is basically redundant** – it only adds several extra steps for verification while doing nothing for the actual security. You get exactly the same value from verifying a signature made directly against the file that you wanted to verify.

Nevertheless, the Mozilla FTP server *does* include SHA256SUMS manifests containing every file belonging to the release (including Windows and macOS), together with a PGP signature.

- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/83.0/SHA256SUMS
- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/83.0/SHA256SUMS.asc

Comment: Great response, thanks! btw, Mozilla's wiki has a great article enumerating the many disadvantages of the X.509 PKI model (eg used by Microsoft's Authenticode) compared to "people-based security" (eg `gpg`) https://wiki.mozilla.org/Apps/Security/Distribution#Advantages_of_People-based_security

Comment: I do not see where that article would compare the X.509 PKI model with PGP WoT, and I couldn't find any mentions of general PKI issues such as certificate cost, misissuance, EV validation, and so on. Rather it seems to be listing arguments about file signing vs _transport protection_ (i.e. the usage of HTTPS or FTPS). For example, it says "SSL PKI is host-based" – this is true for X.509-based TLS but completely untrue for X.509 in general (be it Authenticode or S/MIME or PKCS#7 signatures); code-signing certificates _are_ held by people and their signatures are fully verifiable offline.